# Caliburn.Micro set status of controls

Tags: .net, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I try to set the enabled/visibility status of all my controls which belong to a viewmodel inside the OnActivate method. So far this is no problem but I'm not sure if there is a better approach to do this without accessing the view from the viewmodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use binding. In XAML, set the `Visibility` property to bind to a public property on your view model, and use the standard `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to convert your boolean view model public property to a valid `Visibility` value.

If you wish to create a general solution to allow configurability of the visibility of any view element, then one option is to plug into the Caliburn.Micro binding process. For example, you can add another element to the `ViewModelBinder.BindProperties` invocation list.

I haven't tested this, but here this is done in the `Configure` method of your bootstrapper:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    ViewModelBinder.BindProperties += (namedElements, viewModelType) =>
    {                    
        foreach (var element in namedElements)
        {
            // Generate a unique identifier for an element on a particular view
            string uniqueElementId = string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewModelType.FullName, element.Name);

            // Calculate the visibility of the element based on unique element id
            bool elementVisible = ...

            // Set the element's visibility
            element.Visibility = elementVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    };

   ... other configuration code
}
```

The `BindProperties` public `Func` gets a collection of all of the named elements on your view, as well as the Type of the view model that is being bound to. You can use this information to uniquely identify each view control, and then calculate the visibility from your data based on that unique identifier.

Note that setting the `Visibility` of each element in code like this will override any bindings that are present on the `Visibility` property in XAML.

Comment: This would mean that I would have to create the bindings for every window. I would like to have a generic approach where I would just extend the Screen class to execute my custom code. Example for this would be that the user has a text file where he writes something like Window.control.property = false and the application uses this information to set the values. So I don't want to create a property like <mycontrol>IsVisible and bind it manually (or tell caliburn to bind it for me) for everything.

Comment: Sorry, I've read that 5 times and I'm still not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you need the visibility of each control configurable by the end user? It sounds hideous, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: It should be configurable from the superusers (inside the database). So the application will check inside the database for the securities and set the visibility/enabled status of the controls. The functionality which is behind these buttons/fields is always on the server so this is no real security check but just a way to avoid a lot of useless stuff in the UI.

Comment: Assuming you can find a mechanism for uniquely identify a control on a particular view, and relating that back to a column value in a database, then you might be better trying to integrate your logic into the Caliburn.Micro binding process, rather than trying to implement a custom screen type. In other words, Caliburn.Micro exposes public Func delegate instances for each step of its binding process. You could plug into the appropriate step and perform your custom logic there.

Comment: That sounds really interessting. Do you have an example of doing this (I am just starting with Caliburn.Micro).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve by this. Nevertheless, using (and changing) VisualState of the view or C.M. guard methods might do the work.